# How to insert a row to table through database link in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables in 2 different connections in oracle. I call it is server connection and client connection. And I created a database link to transfer data and it works fine. When I insert a new record into table in client from server through database link, it's ok! But when I select that table in client, that record is not displayed. For example, I have a table in client with a record "1".

In server side:

```
select * from [table_name]@[database_link_name]
```

It work fine! I can get the record "1". And I insert a new record in client table from server and select again:

```
insert into [table_name]@[database_link_name] values(2)
```

OK, I can get 2 records "1" and "2". But in client side, when I select that table:

```
select * from [tblname]
```

It just returns the record "1". How can I get 2 records same in server side. Where is my problem? The insert command in server or select command in client?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you committed the insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following your description, you just need to issue a `commit` on the 'server' session that did the `insert`.

A session can never see uncommitted data from other sessions, whether the changes were made locally or remotely. The database link isn't really relevant, you'd see the same effect if the data had been inserted from another session on the 'client'.

Read more about [concurrency and consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm) and [transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/server.1111/e25789/transact.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: oh I see, I don't commit on the server side. Thank you!